# Looping over UserProfiles

Tags: user-profile-service

I have a number of users who need to have some properties of their Profile updated. I've been using UserProfileManager.GetEnumerator to get a collection of all users in the system and am then selecting individual users by their WorkEmail property.

```
    Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell -erroraction SilentlyContinue

    $mySiteHostSite = "<siteurl>"
    $context = Get-SPServiceContext $mySiteHostSite
    $profileManager = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($context)

    $names = @("example1@company.co.nz","example2@company.co.nz")
    $profiles = $profileManager.GetEnumerator()

    foreach($name in $names){
        $profile =  ($profiles | where { $_['WorkEmail'] -like "*$($name)" })
        $profile.AccountName
    }
```

The issue I am having is that each time the loop iterates the $profiles object gets cleared out. I can make this work by replacing:

```
    $profile =  ($profiles | where { $_['WorkEmail'] -like "*$($name)"
```

with:

```
    $profile =  ($profileManager.GetEnumerator() | where { $_['WorkEmail'] -like "*$($name)"
```

however I'd rather not have to repeatedly make this call. Is there a way to ensure that the $profiles collection is maintained through this loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented the following solution -

```
    function loadAllProfiles($profiles){
        foreach($prof in $profiles){
            $profilesArr += $prof
        }

        return $profilesArr
    }
```

Just looping the collection and populating a separate array. It does still seem odd that making a selection from the GetProfiles object clears out the result but this solution has resolved my issue.